# is it safe to allow Javascript content for a database column with type as String

Tags: javascript, sql, security, sql-injection

In our application, there is a free form text field. From the UI, we are restricting the user to enter script. However, it is still possible for user to enter some script using Postman. So, should there be a sanitisation required at server side also before inserting to the database? Or, since this is JavaScript, only UI has to deal with it when the data is displayed back on browser?

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Prevention_Framework_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "sanitize" the data for the sake of preventing SQL injection, if you insert using SQL query parameters.

If you want to prevent XSS, then sanitize the data before you output.